# Prism 5.0 wrap Model Attributes in ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Hello I am relatively new with Prism but here is my question:

I am currently using Prism 5 with WPF. I have created a model, viewmodel and view. The View gets updated when an attribute from model changes. My problem is: when I want to process the Attribute from the model(for example another attribute name), the view does not get updated. Heres my Code. I'll be very thnakful if you could help me.

When RunTinting in the model Changes, the view does not get updated.

Model

```
public class MyModel :BindableBase

{               
    private Boolean _RunTinting;
    public Boolean RunTinting
    {
        get { return _RunTinting; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _RunTinting, value); }
    }
```

Viewmodel

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : BindableBase
{

    private MyModel model;
    public MyModel Model
    {
        get { return this.model; }
        set { SetProperty(ref this.model, value); }
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        this.Model=new MyModel();

    }


    public Boolean RunTinting2
    {
        get { return this.model.RunTinting; }
        set { SetProperty(ref this._RunTinting, value); }
    }

 }
```

XAML

```
<Label x:Name="label1_Copy11" Content="{Binding RunTinting2}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="366,320,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="25" Width="85" >
```

Comment: Property changes fire events on the instance whose property changes.  This does not magically transfer to other objects that expose the properties of another object.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

this is how I solved this problem, thank you Rachel and Will.

ViewModel

```
    public void InitModel()
    {
        Model.PropertyChanged += Model_PropertyChanged;
    }

    private void Model_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "RunTinting")
        { 
            OnPropertyChanged("RunTinting2");
        }

    }
```

@mm8, I tried your solution, but it didnt work... but thank you anyways for the time taken.

I do not know why my answer has negative ratings. It works and respect the mvvm model!

Comment: This is not a good solution as you are mixing Model and ViewModel. ViewModel should not be notifyiing View via INotifyPropertyChanged. ViewModel classes should inherit from BindableBase, Model should be POCOs. You will run into performance and threading issues if you create and load object data via some form of ORM such as EF or Dapper.

Comment: The Viewmodel inherits from BindableBase, so does the model. This is possible with the Prism Framework. You can check the example Projects from Prism.

Comment: As a long time Prism and MVVM practitioner - you shouldn't do it regardless of what their examples show.

Comment: toadflakz could you elaborate more about the performance and threading issues.                                                                                                       The POCO model as you say would have to update the viewmodel, and this can be done with BindableBase. Do you implement INotifyPropertyChange instead. (Bindablebase already implements INotifyPropertyChange)

Comment: PropertyChanged can only be handled on the Dispatcher thread. If you load or modify notifiable objects on a background thread, the UI will not receive the change notifications. If you load 100s of rows and every property on a Model object raises a notification, you will be raising 100s of extra events for no reason - this can and does lead to performance degradation over time, especially if you link changes in other properties based on the notifications. Model objects should be for encapsulating data only, ViewModel is for binding to View and monitoring change, View is for presenting the data.

Comment: How do you then inform the Viewmodel when the Model changes? I am writing a program where the data in the model changes every 10ms. With the BindableBase Class from Prism I can inform the ViewModel about changes in the Model.

Comment: Okay, realtime update is a different story. Model in that case should use some form of notification to the VM, but VM will still need to marshal PropertyChanged events to Dispatcher thread using  Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() as there is no way you will be able to handle the processing of the updates on the Dispatcher thread alone. I'd suggest you look at RX framework (Reactive Extensions).

Comment: I am updating the Model from a Task every 10ms. With BindableBase the Model updates the ViewModel and in turn the ViewModel  updates the View. Unitl now everything is working fine. I am not experiencing any sort of problem...

Comment: I do not know why my answer has negative ratings. It works and respect the mvvm model!

Answer (score 0):

If you set the *model* property dynamically the view should bind to this property instead of the view model property:

```
<Label x:Name="label1_Copy11" Content="{Binding Model.RunTinting}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="366,320,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="25" Width="85" >
```

Because the view model won't raise any change notifications when a property of the model is set to a new value.

The other option is to set the model property through the wrapper property of the view model, i.e. instead of setting the model property directly you set the view model property. Make sure that you then set the model's property in the setter of the wrapper property and that you raise a PropertyChanged event for the view model property that the view binds to:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : BindableBase
{
...
   public Boolean RunTinting2
  {
    get { return this.model.RunTinting; }
    set { this.model.RunTinting = value; OnPropertyChanged("RunTinting2"); }
  }
}

<Label x:Name="label1_Copy11" Content="{Binding RunTinting2}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="366,320,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="25" Width="85" >
```

Comment: but is not the propertychanged event already in the Bindable Class?

Comment: Could you please provide a reproducible sample of how and where you set the property then? You either need to set and bind to the model property or set or bind to the view model property. And raise the PropertyChanged event in the setter of the property that you set.

Comment: @user7268733 If using the second solutions, you need to hook up a PropertyChanged event handler to the `model` that copies the change event to your ViewModel. For example, `model.PropertyChanged` handler might say "if (e.PropertyName == "RunTinting") OnPropertyChanged("RunTinting2");` to make sure the same change event fires on the ViewModel layer.